# I'm trying to display breadcrumbs on product page in magento but it gives me a fatal error

Tags: php, magento

This is the line I have put in catalog/product/view.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml(); ?>
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in ../catalog/product/view.phtml on line 159
```

Any solutions to this? I am running Magento 1.4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

**XML**

Make sure you have your configuration setup in your theme's page.xml

```
<block reference="header">
   <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
</block>
```

**View**

You need to call the HTML item itself

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
```

Comment: I have done so, I am not getting any errors anymore. However, breadcrumbs still don't appear.

Comment: Make sure you have breadcrumbs turned on in your CMS. I think it's the Web Tab > Configuration > General. (Switch to your store view)

Comment: Last thing to do is check the breadcrumb phtml file. Make sure it has the code in it and trace it back to see why it's empty.

Comment: Okay, the file breadcumbs.phtml has a code. It appears that it doesn't get included into the view.

Comment: Type some garbage in there and see if it pops up on your page.

Comment: Oh! ..and dont forget to clear your cache, if your using it. Template files are cached.

Comment: I have disabled cache for development so that's not the case either. I'm 100% positive the problem is the file breadcumbs.phtml not getting included

Answer (score 0):

I had this same quandary. I managed to get breadcrumbs on the products page by adding the following to app/design/frontend/THEME/default/layout/calalog.xml

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <-- existing content -->
    <reference name="content">
        <-- existing blocks -->
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <-- existing blocks -->
            <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
        </block>
     </reference>
    <-- existing content -->
</catalog_product_view>
```

Then in catalog/product/view.phtml add the following where you would like the breadcrumbs to appear.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
```